# Wordpress if statement not echoing correct URI

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created an if statement to check if the current wordpress page/post has a feature image set. If it does not I want the script to echo the URI for the placeholder image. The script run's without any PHP errors however when no feature image is available it echos the following `background: url(h)` and not the URI for the placeholder. I can see the issue is with the inline echoing `$image[0]` however I don't know how to fix this.

```
  <?php if(is_home()) {
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_option('page_for_posts')),'full');
    } elseif (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail, page_for_posts' );
    } else {
      $image = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placeholder.png';
    }
  ?>

  <div class="hero-inner" style="background: url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
     [...] 
  </div>
```

Comment: in else case defined only $image not $image[0]

Answer (score 1):

```
if(is_home()) {
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_option('page_for_posts')),'full');
    } elseif (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail, page_for_posts' );
    } 

    if($image){
        $image = $image[0];
        }
            else {
      $image = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placeholder.png';
    }
  ?>

  <div class="hero-inner" style="background: url(<?php echo $image; ?>) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
     [...] 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the var $image to $image[0] for the last else works.

```
 <?php if(is_home()) {
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_option('page_for_posts')),'full');
    } elseif (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail, page_for_posts' );
    } else {
      $image[0] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placeholder.png';
    }
  ?>

  <div class="hero-inner" style="background: url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
     [...] 
  </div>
```